# apache virtual hosts not working

Tags: 14.04, apache2, virtualhost

I have production server with apache/2.4.7 on ubuntu 14.04. I have several virtual hosts on it. This server located on hetzner. I decide to transfer my server on more powerfull server. I create snapshot of my old server and transfer it on new. Everything work fine but when i try to access on one of my domains that i transfer on new server i got just default apache webpage that stored on `000-default.conf` on line:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

i tried to aplly this command:

```
a2ensite mysite.conf
```

but i got this message: `Site mysite already enabled`
i tried to `a2dissite mysite.conf` restart server, `a2ensite mysite.conf` then restart server once again. but i still got default page. Here is example of `mysite`:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com.ua:80>
    ServerName mysite.com.ua
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com.ua
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/www/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    CustomLog /var/www/mysite/logs/apache_access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/mysite/logs/apache_error.log

    Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/static/
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media/ /var/www/mysite/media/
    <Directory /var/www/mysite/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

here is my `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see i use wsgi, but it still doesn't work when i use pure html. Can somebody help me with it. Thanks

Comment: After migrating the sites to new server your sites are not accessible. Is it?

Comment: Is the domain that you are trying to access is pointing to the new server?

Comment: Yes, i point domains on new server.

Comment: I'm looking at your configuration. Could you try, please, to change `<VirtualHost mysite.com.ua:80>` with `<VirtualHost *:80>`. I don't know why, but I had similar problem while ago, and this was the solution. Maybe it is connected with `/etc/hosts`...

Comment: @SpasSpasov thank you it worls! post it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<VirtualHost mysite.com.ua:80>` with `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

I don't know what is the reason of this behaviour, but I had similar problem while ago, and this was the solution. Maybe it is connected with `/etc/hosts`.

It would be good someone, who knows the reason, give us an explanation.